# unused argument (family = binomial)

Tags: r

The code I put in is this below:

```
Attitude.lmer<- lmer(Sub ~ Lang+Gender+Years+Disc+Course+Location + (1|Name), data = Attitude, family = binomial)
```

`Sub` is a binary outcome. `Lang`, `Gender`, `Years`, `Disc`, `Course`, and `Location` are all fixed effect variables. `Name` is the only random effect variable. I have read Tagliamonte & Baayen (2012) a couple of times, which I found very similar to my study. But for some reason, why I use the same code, it shows this:

`Error in lmer(Sub ~ Lang + Gender + Years + Disc + Course + Location + : unused argument (family = binomial)`

I'm not sure what goes wrong here. I'm very new to R and data analysis.

Thanks.

Comment: If I use glmer instead of lmer, it then works. But I'm not sure if the result is correct or not.

Comment: You'll need to use the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package to specify the family.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230634/glmer-vs-lmer-what-is-best-for-a-binomial-outcome

Comment: Thank you all! This helps very much! I got it solved through glmer.